# SPA e MPA em Angular

Tags: angular, single-page-application

Não encontrei muitos sobre criação de MPA com angular, só encontro artigos de SPA.
alguém poderia me indicar artigos ou link's para estudar, fico grato!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia, cara voce nao encontra muita coisa sobre MPA (angular2) por que o conceito do Angular é de fazer as APIs como SPA diminuindo processamento banda e etc se você quer fazer MPA talvez nao seja o angular a melhor ferramenta mas estou deixando um curso completo de angular 2 aqui, bons estudos!

[Curso de Angular2 completo -Loiane Groner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPOMG0D57S0&list=PLGxZ4Rq3BOBoSRcKWEdQACbUCNWLczg2G)